# if previous page url with “-cn” ending then change content in current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a site in both English and Chinese language, now I need to detect if previous page url with "-cn" ending (so will know it is chinese page) then change some content in current page(default is in English). Thank you.

code below, sorry I'm too new to JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
   //*detect if previous url without "-cn"ending do nothing if with "-cn" then below
   //*change content inside to "new"<div class="block"></div>
});

<div class="block">old</div>
```

Comment: check my below answer. @wang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: i think you want something like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var referrer =  document.referrer;
        if(referrer.indexOf("-cn")>-1)
        {
        // referrer url contain the "-cn"
        }
        else
        {
        // Not contain "-cn"
        }
    });
```